# Why Does Static Lighting Not Work in My Unreal Engine 5.1?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal

I have a light in my scene which was originally a Stationary Light and it worked fine.
[image]

I wanted to change it to a static light  to optimize performance, but after changing it and building the lights, the scene turned dark.
[image]

I have confirmed that the objects here are of a static type, but I am not sure what the problem is and I'm seeking assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable Lumen? It's default for UE5 is on. Lumen will disable static lightning. See the documentation of Lumen: *When Lumen is enabled for a project, precomputed static lighting contributions are disabled and all lightmaps are hidden.* https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/lumen-global-illumination-and-reflections-in-unreal-engine/

Comment: YES! Thanks Bro. So should I disable the option "allow static lighting" in the project settings when Lumen is enable?

Comment: You can't use static lightning or baked lightning in combination with Lumen global illumination. You have to decide wether you want to use Lumen or not.